# CMake BISON_TARGET prevent header generation

Tags: cmake, bison

Have looked everywhere. Is there no way to prevent CMake from generating a header file with `BISON_TARGET`?

Comment: Can you even achieve this with valid `bison` command line functionality? Can you provide some context for why you want to disable header generation? Did you try leaving the third argument blank when calling `BISON_TARGET`?

Comment: yeah `bison -p xml -o xml.cc xml.y` Im disabling because I have my own header.

Comment: Gotcha, I'm not seeing a supported way to disable it with CMake. The code [here](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/6f7853cb42b75715d38a71bce3123390b78a502a/Modules/FindBISON.cmake#L240) is **always** called if the `BISON_TARGET` arguments are valid, which appears to set the header generation. You could just set the `DEFINES_FILE` argument (docs [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBISON.html)) to define a specific header file to be generated, but just ignore the generated file.

Answer (score 0):

Heres what I ended up doing

```
# Create target for xml
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(xml echo "Creating xml.cc" DEPENDS xml.cc)

ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
  OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/xml.cc
  COMMAND ${BISON_EXECUTABLE}
  ARGS -y ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/xml.y -p xml -o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/xml.cc
  )
```

then you later you need

```
add_executable (parse
  ${SOURCES}
  ...
  xml.cc
  )

add_dependencies(parse xml)
```

and

```
target_include_directories(parse PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

If you want generated files in the build dir.